# Does the density of the brushes used in a DC motor increase efficiency?

Tags: dc-motor, electromagnetism, efficiency

I'm doing a science paper about DC motors and efficiency and I need to test one part to see whether or not the efficiency increases or decreases. I think I will do the brushes and I'm wondering if the density of the brush affects the power outage/efficiency of a dc motor at all.

Comment: Density? Brush parameters would be material, force, contact area, thickness (amount of wear they can tolerate), maybe a few others, what do you mean by *density?*

Comment: By density, do you mean the density of the material the brushes are made from or the number of brushes in close proximity to each other?

Comment: By density I mean the... thickness of the brush?

Answer (score 1):

Several aspects of brush design have some effect on DC motor efficiency. That would include friction, brush resistance, and contact resistance or contact voltage drop. Those items would be partly determined by brush dimensions and material. The effect would be influenced by armature voltage, current and operating speed and perhaps some other factors.

For carbon brushes, brush resistance is simply the resistance of the brush material. The resistivity is determined by the composition of the brushes, graphite, a binding additive and sometimes copper powder and other metal powders. Some very small motors have spring brushes made of metal alloys.

Comment: Could you elaborate on brush resistance a bit more? Thanks!